# Docker / Windows Server 2016 - Access is denied when trying to pull image

Tags: docker

I have install Docker version 20.10.4 on Windows Server 2016 (10.0 14393) to be able to run Windows Container (Linux container is not in my scope).

I try to pull image "mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:sac2016" but it failed (after download) when extracting with following error :

```
C:\Windows\system32>docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:sac2016 
sac2016: Pulling from windows/nanoserver 
bce2fbc256ea: Extracting [==================================================>]  252.7MB/252.7MB
6f2071dcd729: Download complete 
failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: 
output: hcsshim::ProcessBaseLayer \\?\D:\DockerData\windowsfilter\4fba31d282f754bb1d6207bd0395cb02b580a75c495 
414058b56b401bad40026:Access is denied.
```

I have start dockerd manually (via command dockerd --exec-opt isolation=process  -D  --log-level=debug --data-root="D:\DockerData") and last line is :

```
output: hcsshim::ProcessBaseLayer \\\\?\\D:\\DockerData\\windowsfilter\\f967f....47766: Access is denied.
```

complete output :

```
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.230069500-04:00" level=info msg="Starting up"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.234070000-04:00" level=debug msg="Listener created for HTTP on npipe (//./pipe/docker_engine)"time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.239070000-04:00" level=info msg="Windows default isolation mode: process"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.239070000-04:00" level=debug msg="Stackdump - waiting signal at Global\\stackdump-8008"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.240070800-04:00" level=debug msg="Using default logging driver json-file"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.240070800-04:00" level=debug msg="[graphdriver] trying provided driver: windowsfilter"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.240070800-04:00" level=debug msg="WindowsGraphDriver InitFilter at D:\\DockerData\\windowsfilter"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.240070800-04:00" level=debug msg="Initialized graph driver windowsfilter"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.240070800-04:00" level=debug msg="No quota support for local volumes in D:\\DockerData\\volumes: Filesystem does not support, or has not enabled quotas"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.250074100-04:00" level=debug msg="Max Concurrent Downloads: 3"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.250074100-04:00" level=debug msg="Max Concurrent Uploads: 5"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.250074100-04:00" level=debug msg="Max Download Attempts: 5"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.250074100-04:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.250074100-04:00" level=debug msg="Option Experimental: false"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.250074100-04:00" level=debug msg="Option DefaultDriver: nat"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.250074100-04:00" level=debug msg="Option DefaultNetwork: nat"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.250074100-04:00" level=debug msg="Network Control Plane MTU: 1500"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.251073400-04:00" level=info msg="Restoring existing overlay networks from HNS into docker"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.251073400-04:00" level=debug msg="[GET]=>[/networks/] Request : "
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.258075000-04:00" level=debug msg="Network Response : [ { \"CurrentEndpointCount\" : 0, \"ExternalInterfaceAddress\" : \"00-50-56-92-F7-4C\", \"ID\" : \"955f2216-b35d-44bb-8882-ff89790c3587\", \"MacPools\" : [ { \"EndMacAddress\" : \"00-15-5D-CF-7F-FF\", \"StartMacAddress\" : \"00-15-5D-CF-70-00\" } ], \"MaxConcurrentEndpoints\" : 0, \"NATName\" : \"H955f2216-b35d-44bb-8882-ff89790c3587\", \"Name\" : \"nat\", \"Policies\" : [  ], \"Subnets\" : [ { \"AddressPrefix\" : \"172.21.0.0/20\", \"GatewayAddress\" : \"172.21.0.1\" } ], \"SwitchGuid\" : \"f8f84d6d-20ca-48c2-b354-b8e43fa03681\", \"TotalEndpoints\" : 0, \"Type\" : \"nat\", \"Version\" : 4294967297 } ]"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.260075800-04:00" level=debug msg="Network  nat (359449a) restored"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.264082600-04:00" level=debug msg="[GET]=>[/networks/] Request : "
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.269077200-04:00" level=debug msg="Network Response : [ { \"CurrentEndpointCount\" : 0, \"ExternalInterfaceAddress\" : \"00-50-56-92-F7-4C\", \"ID\" : \"955f2216-b35d-44bb-8882-ff89790c3587\", \"MacPools\" : [ { \"EndMacAddress\" : \"00-15-5D-CF-7F-FF\", \"StartMacAddress\" : \"00-15-5D-CF-70-00\" } ], \"MaxConcurrentEndpoints\" : 0, \"NATName\" : \"H955f2216-b35d-44bb-8882-ff89790c3587\", \"Name\" : \"nat\", \"Policies\" : [  ], \"Subnets\" : [ { \"AddressPrefix\" : \"172.21.0.0/20\", \"GatewayAddress\" : \"172.21.0.1\" } ], \"SwitchGuid\" : \"f8f84d6d-20ca-48c2-b354-b8e43fa03681\", \"TotalEndpoints\" : 0, \"Type\" : \"nat\", \"Version\" : 4294967297 } ]"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.270081900-04:00" level=debug msg="Launching DNS server for network \"none\""
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.287367700-04:00" level=debug msg="releasing IPv4 pools from network nat (359449af67f8444ab8cfba4fa4dabd849ef57eeb21f918af9e308f1fabbf5cc2)"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.287367700-04:00" level=debug msg="ReleaseAddress(172.21.0.0/20, 172.21.0.1)"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.288366100-04:00" level=debug msg="ReleasePool(172.21.0.0/20)"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.297123600-04:00" level=debug msg="cleanupServiceDiscovery for network:359449af67f8444ab8cfba4fa4dabd849ef57eeb21f918af9e308f1fabbf5cc2"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.298128800-04:00" level=debug msg="cleanupServiceBindings for 359449af67f8444ab8cfba4fa4dabd849ef57eeb21f918af9e308f1fabbf5cc2"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.311341600-04:00" level=debug msg="Allocating IPv4 pools for network nat (359449af67f8444ab8cfba4fa4dabd849ef57eeb21f918af9e308f1fabbf5cc2)"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.311341600-04:00" level=debug msg="RequestPool(LocalDefault, 172.21.0.0/20, , map[], false)"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.312338500-04:00" level=debug msg="RequestAddress(172.21.0.0/20, 172.21.0.1, map[RequestAddressType:com.docker.network.gateway])"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.312338500-04:00" level=debug msg="[GET]=>[/endpoints/] Request : "
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.318336200-04:00" level=debug msg="Network Response : [  ]"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.324346600-04:00" level=debug msg="Launching DNS server for network \"nat\""
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.324346600-04:00" level=debug msg="[GET]=>[/networks/955f2216-b35d-44bb-8882-ff89790c3587] Request : "
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.330336400-04:00" level=debug msg="Network Response : { \"CurrentEndpointCount\" : 0, \"ExternalInterfaceAddress\" : \"00-50-56-92-F7-4C\", \"ID\" : \"955f2216-b35d-44bb-8882-ff89790c3587\", \"MacPools\" : [ { \"EndMacAddress\" : \"00-15-5D-CF-7F-FF\", \"StartMacAddress\" : \"00-15-5D-CF-70-00\" } ], \"MaxConcurrentEndpoints\" : 0, \"NATName\" : \"H955f2216-b35d-44bb-8882-ff89790c3587\", \"Name\" : \"nat\", \"Policies\" : [  ], \"Subnets\" : [ { \"AddressPrefix\" : \"172.21.0.0/20\", \"GatewayAddress\" : \"172.21.0.1\" } ], \"SwitchGuid\" : \"f8f84d6d-20ca-48c2-b354-b8e43fa03681\", \"TotalEndpoints\" : 0, \"Type\" : \"nat\", \"Version\" : 4294967297 }"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.330336400-04:00" level=debug msg="Binding a resolver on network nat gateway 172.21.0.1"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:46.330336400-04:00" level=error msg="Resolver Setup/Start failed for container nat, \"error in opening name server socket listen udp 172.21.0.1:53: bind: The requested address is not valid in its context.\""
time="2021-05-04T22:50:47.332425400-04:00" level=debug msg="Binding a resolver on network nat gateway 172.21.0.1"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:47.332508100-04:00" level=error msg="Resolver Setup/Start failed for container nat, \"error in opening name server socket listen udp 172.21.0.1:53: bind: The requested address is not valid in its context.\""
time="2021-05-04T22:50:48.334572000-04:00" level=debug msg="Binding a resolver on network nat gateway 172.21.0.1"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:48.334642500-04:00" level=error msg="Resolver Setup/Start failed for container nat, \"error in opening name server socket listen udp 172.21.0.1:53: bind: The requested address is not valid in its context.\""
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.350169300-04:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.351166500-04:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=b24528647a graphdriver(s)=windowsfilter version=20.10.4
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.352166600-04:00" level=info msg="starting telemetry service"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.352166600-04:00" level=debug msg="Docker daemon will send anonymous usage telemetry"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.353167400-04:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.358166300-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering routers"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.358166300-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/checkpoints"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.358166300-04:00" level=debug msg="Config reload - waiting signal at Global\\docker-daemon-config-8008"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.359170200-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/checkpoints"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.359170200-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering DELETE, /containers/{name}/checkpoints/{checkpoint}"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.360165100-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering HEAD, /containers/{name:.*}/archive"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.360165100-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /containers/json"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.360165100-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/export"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.361165500-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/changes"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.363171000-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/json"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.363171000-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/top"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.364165500-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/logs"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.364165500-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/stats"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.365171100-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/attach/ws"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.365171100-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /exec/{id:.*}/json"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.365171100-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/archive"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.366169100-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/create"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.366169100-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/kill"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.366169100-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/pause"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.367169100-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/unpause"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.367169100-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/restart"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.367169100-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/start"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.368168800-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/stop"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.368168800-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/wait"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.368168800-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/resize"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.369169200-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/attach"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.369169200-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/copy"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.369169200-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/exec"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.369169200-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /exec/{name:.*}/start"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.370167200-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /exec/{name:.*}/resize"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.370167200-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/rename"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.371166400-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/update"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.371166400-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/prune"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.371166400-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /commit"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.372169200-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering PUT, /containers/{name:.*}/archive"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.375169600-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering DELETE, /containers/{name:.*}"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.375169600-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /images/json"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.375169600-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /images/search"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.376168500-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /images/get"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.376168500-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /images/{name:.*}/get"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.376168500-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /images/{name:.*}/history"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.377170500-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /images/{name:.*}/json"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.377170500-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /images/load"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.377170500-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /images/create"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.378172800-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /images/{name:.*}/push"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.378172800-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /images/{name:.*}/tag"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.379169700-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /images/prune"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.379169700-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering DELETE, /images/{name:.*}"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.379169700-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering OPTIONS, /{anyroute:.*}"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.380172100-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /_ping"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.380172100-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering HEAD, /_ping"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.380172100-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /events"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.381170900-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /info"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.381170900-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /version"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.381170900-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /system/df"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.382170900-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /auth"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.382170900-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /volumes"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.382170900-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /volumes/{name:.*}"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.383170200-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /volumes/create"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.383170200-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /volumes/prune"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.383170200-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering DELETE, /volumes/{name:.*}"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.384167400-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /build"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.386170600-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /build/prune"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.386170600-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /build/cancel"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.386170600-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /session"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.387170600-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /swarm/init"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.387170600-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /swarm/join"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.387170600-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /swarm/leave"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.388167100-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /swarm"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.388167100-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /swarm/unlockkey"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.388167100-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /swarm/update"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.389168300-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /swarm/unlock"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.389168300-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /services"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.389168300-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /services/{id}"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.390171400-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /services/create"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.390171400-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /services/{id}/update"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.390171400-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering DELETE, /services/{id}"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.391169900-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /services/{id}/logs"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.391169900-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /nodes"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.391169900-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /nodes/{id}"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.392168700-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering DELETE, /nodes/{id}"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.392168700-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /nodes/{id}/update"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.392168700-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /tasks"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.393171500-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /tasks/{id}"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.393171500-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /tasks/{id}/logs"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.393171500-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /secrets"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.394172700-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /secrets/create"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.394172700-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering DELETE, /secrets/{id}"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.395171100-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /secrets/{id}"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.397171900-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /secrets/{id}/update"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.397171900-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /configs"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.397171900-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /configs/create"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.398171900-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering DELETE, /configs/{id}"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.398171900-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /configs/{id}"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.398171900-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /configs/{id}/update"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.399172000-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /plugins"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.399172000-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /plugins/{name:.*}/json"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.399172000-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /plugins/privileges"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.400172000-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering DELETE, /plugins/{name:.*}"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.400172000-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /plugins/{name:.*}/enable"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.400172000-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /plugins/{name:.*}/disable"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.401172800-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /plugins/pull"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.401172800-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /plugins/{name:.*}/push"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.401172800-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /plugins/{name:.*}/upgrade"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.402173600-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /plugins/{name:.*}/set"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.402173600-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /plugins/create"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.402173600-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /distribution/{name:.*}/json"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.404171600-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /grpc"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.405170900-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /networks"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.405170900-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /networks/"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.405170900-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /networks/{id:.+}"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.406174800-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /networks/create"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.408180700-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /networks/{id:.*}/connect"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.408180700-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /networks/{id:.*}/disconnect"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.408180700-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /networks/prune"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.409171300-04:00" level=debug msg="Registering DELETE, /networks/{id:.*}"
time="2021-05-04T22:50:49.409171300-04:00" level=info msg="API listen on //./pipe/docker_engine"
time="2021-05-04T22:54:11.890828600-04:00" level=debug msg="Calling POST /v1.41/images/create?fromImage=mcr.microsoft.com%2Fwindows%2Fnanoserver&tag=sac2016"
time="2021-05-04T22:54:11.896828600-04:00" level=debug msg="hostDir: C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\certs.d\\mcr.microsoft.com"
time="2021-05-04T22:54:11.896828600-04:00" level=debug msg="Trying to pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver from https://mcr.microsoft.com v2"
time="2021-05-04T22:54:12.377035700-04:00" level=debug msg="Pulling ref from V2 registry: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:sac2016"
time="2021-05-04T22:54:12.755671000-04:00" level=debug msg="pulling blob \"sha256:6f2071dcd7294537bba55b3061704ef1370748e91982193b9e0fa4ebc114589b\""
time="2021-05-04T22:54:12.755671000-04:00" level=debug msg="pulling blob \"sha256:bce2fbc256ea437a87dadac2f69aabd25bed4f56255549090056c1131fad0277\""
time="2021-05-04T22:54:12.940594400-04:00" level=debug msg="Pulling sha256:6f2071dcd7294537bba55b3061704ef1370748e91982193b9e0fa4ebc114589b from foreign URL https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2028818"
time="2021-05-04T22:54:12.976594200-04:00" level=debug msg="Pulling sha256:bce2fbc256ea437a87dadac2f69aabd25bed4f56255549090056c1131fad0277 from foreign URL https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=837858"
time="2021-05-04T22:54:23.000554300-04:00" level=debug msg="Downloaded 6f2071dcd729 to tempfile D:\\DockerData\\tmp\\GetImageBlob523969534"
time="2021-05-04T22:54:32.564759000-04:00" level=debug msg="Downloaded bce2fbc256ea to tempfile D:\\DockerData\\tmp\\GetImageBlob782090565"
time="2021-05-04T22:54:32.613761100-04:00" level=debug msg="unpigz binary not found, falling back to go gzip library"
time="2021-05-04T22:54:54.814671900-04:00" level=debug msg="Cleaning up layer f967f2aa860368344d788ebf8102f3043b4b2b58366e874b595e64df4bd47766: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: hcsshim::ProcessBaseLayer \\\\?\\D:\\DockerData\\windowsfilter\\f967f2aa860368344d788ebf8102f3043b4b2b58366e874b595e64df4bd47766: Access is denied."
time="2021-05-04T22:55:00.663189700-04:00" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: hcsshim::ProcessBaseLayer \\\\?\\D:\\DockerData\\windowsfilter\\f967f2aa860368344d788ebf8102f3043b4b2b58366e874b595e64df4bd47766: Access is denied."
```

I have trace file system activity with ProcMon.exe and I wondering if issue appear when LayerID folder is create ?

[image]

Docker info return this :

```
C:\Windows\system32>docker info
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker Application (Docker Inc., v0.8.0)
  cluster: Manage Mirantis Container Cloud clusters (Mirantis Inc., v1.9.0)
  registry: Manage Docker registries (Docker Inc., 0.1.0)

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 0
 Server Version: 20.10.4
 Storage Driver: windowsfilter
  Windows:
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: ics internal l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay private transparent
  Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gcplogs gelf json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Default Isolation: process
 Kernel Version: 10.0 14393 (14393.4350.amd64fre.rs1_release.210407-2154)
 Operating System: Windows Server 2016 Standard Version 1607 (OS Build 14393.4350)
 OSType: windows
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 8
 Total Memory: 48GiB
 Name: cdopwd-260
 ID: SE6C:3RLY:MBCR:MU2D:ODS3:HTIM:PHSS:HOYC:FFNT:5VMB:LTR4:3EH7
 Docker Root Dir: D:\DockerData
 Debug Mode: true
  File Descriptors: -1
  Goroutines: 20
  System Time: 2021-05-04T22:58:30.0953192-04:00
  EventsListeners: 0
 HTTP Proxy: http://fastweb.int.bell.ca
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Info about my Windows  and Virtual Machine is available (=Yes):

[image]
[image]

Some points :

1. My Windows server is a VMWare instance.
2. I have admin right and dockerd+docker is running on my credential
3. Hyper V is not install.
4. Container feature is installed.
5. Docker is install using powershell

   Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider
6. Docker Compose is install using powershell

   Invoke-WebRequest "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.1/docker-compose-Windows-x86_64.exe" -UseBasicParsing -OutFile $Env:ProgramFiles\Docker\docker-compose.exe
7. I follow this [article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/ja-JP/5dcbdae7-6ef3-4d7f-bf0e-97bbfbae62c8/docker-pull-fails-with-quotaccess-is-deniedquot?forum=windowscontainers) that describe the same issue but without success.
8. I try to setup docker on 2 differents server (same os, same VM environment) and I got same error...

At this point, no idea what I can do, any suggestion please...

Philippe

Comment: Version 1607 of Windows Server 2016 is rather outdated and has very imited docker support. Any chance of updating this at least to Version 1809?

Comment: I agree but it's a company standard for now :(

Comment: We had this issue caused by Defender. We needed to explicitly allow the dockerd.exe in the Defender.