# Windows Container Access is denied. (0x5). using Powershell. But still accessible on Docker Desktop CLI tool

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, windows-container

I am running a `docker-compose up` and spinning up my **Windows** containers.  Then I want to attach to a container.

I tried `docker attach <container id>`, but it crashes the entire docker container for whatever reason.  Then, I tried `docker exec <container name> C:\` to login to `C:\`.

This gives me the error: `container 8504af497601933a0c2e7126e00665da77b9fa71db03c37ce30eb5fa94ee2ee6 encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: Access is denied. (0x5)`

On my Windows 10 machine, I can still access the CLI for the containers using Docker Desktop (even though its inaccessible through CLI), however, I need to use CLI to access it on my Windows Server 2019 machine.  I've tried `C:\`, `C:\Users`, etc , and they all give the same error.

Comment: Somewhat similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67394875/docker-windows-server-2016-access-is-denied-when-trying-to-pull-image

Answer (score 0):

I was running this **erroneous** command:

```
&$Env:ProgramFiles\Docker\docker run hello-world:nanoserver .
```

Which resulted in:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: container encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: Access denied. (0x5).
```

This is due to `.` after `hello-world:nanoserver` which specify the shell to use. The error `Access denied` was coming from inside the container I think.

So try to check if you are specifying a shell which is incorrect.